# When does an object break?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, collision, estimation

We all know when I hit glass with a stone, the glass will shatter, the stone will most likely survive.

If I hit a rubber cube with the same stone, both would probably survive and I might get a stone in my face...

I have a single question how do I calculate that?

Since it was asked I am trying to create a simulation game where things need to impact each other.

I did:

(Vector is XY)
Inpactvector = movementvectorMe + movementvectorOther

Calculate the impact has
InpactDelta = ((1 - SoftnessOther) * (1 - SoftnessMe));

Then I calculate the damage done
InpactForce = (InpactMovement * OtherMass).magnitude * InpactDelta ;

So now I need to know if "Me" is damaged and how much.

So I created

MeHealth
MeHealthThreshold

then I did like

if inpact > MeHealthThreshold
MeHealth = MeHealth - inpact

And it didn't work

Comment: A thin slab of stone shatters much more easily than a window pane.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are talking about how to calculate the amount of force required to break, and which object will break in a given situation. The latter can be found using the first. If the force between them is greater than the force required to break one of the involved objects, then it will break.

About the former...
Every object has some elastic behavior, which varies in its extent. The applied force is attributed to something called "shearing stress" which depends on the magnitude of force and the location of force, etc. The amount by which the object deforms is called "strain".

A graph between stress and strain will look as follows (this is for a more elastic material. It will look different for other materials):

[image: stress strain graph]
(Image courtesy: Google)

The point D is the fracture point. This is when it will break. We need to apply that much stress for the object to break.

Hope this answer helps. Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve) for more information.

Comment: I honestly like your answer. While I don't understand how to use this for my purposes (Simulation) I now have an idea of where to look. Thanks.

Comment: I, or someone else, can possibly help, if you share more details on your purpose, or a more specific question.

Comment: That stress-strain curve is for ductile materials like metals. It does not apply to brittle materials like glass or stone.

Comment: @Pieter It will be a lot steeper, and region between B and D will have shrunk to almost a point. Otherwise, they should be similar. Refer [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/thepAJ5t1wEXsDeg9) image.